Video not playing from local file in Webview
I'm a web developer, so very new to Gradle, Kotlin, and Android development. I've been using ChatGPT to convert a very simple HTML/JS/CSS website into a native app - and for the most part it has worked; however videos aren't playing.
This app needs to run on an Android TV running Android 7 (Nougat).
Below is my basic HTML I've been testing with, but the video just loads as a grey box with a play icon.

The video is an MP4, with the below codec details.

HTML:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Video Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<video id="video_holding">
    <source src="file:///android_asset/assets/videos/holding_video_720.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
</body>
</html>

MainActivity.kt
package com.mytest.app

import android.os.Bundle
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.activity.enableEdgeToEdge
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.material3.Scaffold
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import com.brownforman.jdoceana.ui.theme.JDOceanaTheme

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val webView = WebView(this)

        webView.webViewClient = WebViewClient()
        webView.webChromeClient = WebChromeClient() // This is needed for HTML5 video
        webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        webView.settings.domStorageEnabled = true
        webView.settings.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture = false // Allows autoplay of videos
        webView.settings.allowFileAccess = true

        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html")
        setContentView(webView)
        /*enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContent {
            JDOceanaTheme {
                Scaffold(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) { innerPadding ->
                    Greeting(
                        name = "Android",
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding)
                    )
                }
            }
        }*/
    }
}

@Composable
fun Greeting(name: String, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Text(
        text = "Hello $name!",
        modifier = modifier
    )
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun GreetingPreview() {
    JDOceanaTheme {
        Greeting("Android")
    }
}

AndroidManifest.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Oceana">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>

I've checked the codec of the video and amended it to match ChatGPT's recommendation, imported the additional WebViewClient to my Kotlin file, reduced the HTML to super basic, broken the video link to confirm it can find the file (which I believe it is)... I'm stumped as to why it's not playing.


Place your HTML file (test.html) inside the assets folder, ensuring your file structure looks like this:

    app/src/main/assets/test.html


Place your video file (holding_video_720.mp4) inside the assets folder, ensuring your file structure looks like this:

    app/src/main/assets/videos/holding_video_720.mp4



Load webview in your activity like this:

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
       override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
           enableEdgeToEdge()
           setContent {
               VideoWebViewTheme {
                   VideoWebViewScreen()
               }
           }
       }
   }
   
   @Composable
   fun VideoWebViewScreen() {
       AndroidView(
           modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().fillMaxHeight(),
           factory = { context ->
               WebView(context).apply {
                   settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
                   webViewClient = WebViewClient()
                   // Load the HTML file from the assets folder
                   loadUrl("file:///android_asset/test.html")
               }
           }
       )
   }


Also here isthe updated video_test.html file:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Video Test</title>
    <style>
        /* Make video responsive */
        video {
            width: 100%;
            height: auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<video id="video_holding" controls>
    <source src="file:///android_asset/videos/holding_video_720.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
</body>
</html>

Try this and let me know if it works because i tried this and it is working.
If not working then i am attaching code for your reference.
Reference Code
Happy Coding!!!
